# link from ngnix installed outside docker to a container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, odoo

friends,
I have a ubuntu server with ngnix installed outside of docker.

I have a docker image that has a web application, with an ip for example: 172.17.0.3
(all within the same server)

How can I do it from my nginx to the ip of the name container? for example: "ip container docker"

That structure cannot change, that's how aws service creates it.
* obs: the Ip can change because of that I need as a dynamic variable.

```
upstream openerp {
server "ip container docker":8069;}
```

use: $host or hotname, not work

Comment: Not 100% sure about your question but if you want to reach a specific port of your container from outside, you should expose your container port and then connect to the ip of the vm running the container with the mapped port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should publish your docker container port on the docker host and use `server 127.0.0.1:your_mapped_docker_container_port`.

Read more details in the docker docs https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports

This way docker will take care of everything docker networking related under the hood.

Comment: I tried with 127.0.0.1, but I understand that that would be the local ip of the server, not the ip or name of the container and port that I want to reach (ex: 172.x.x.x.), when I try with 127.x.x.x the page doesn't load.